# Why has this edit suggestion been rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

It's about this question: *[How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript)*

The top answer is very short and somehow "poor" (even if it technically answers the question).
If I want to add another answer there is a message which tries to keep me back from answering and suggests, that I can improve an answer. So okay.

I improved the top answer and listed all other possibilities, which are mentioned in the thread with links to the posts.

[My suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14168795) added this:

> **Edit:**
>
> Since there are so many different possibilities mentioned on this
>   page, here a summary:
>
> **1. indexOf** - (see above)
>
> **2. (ES6) includes** - [go to answer][2], or [this answer][3]
>
> **3. search** - [go to answer][3]
>
> **4. lodash includes** - [go to answer][4]
>
> **5. RegExp** - [go to answer][5]
>
> **6. Match** - [go to answer][6]
>
> Performance tests (http://jsben.ch/#/RVYk7) are showing that indexOf
>   might be the best choice, if it comes to a point where speed matters.

So my question: What is wrong with that? It's a very high frequency question with a poor top answer. What's wrong in improving this answer in this way? I've seen similar improvements a lot.

Comment: Because you significantly changed a answer with over 7700 votes. The rejection reasons in the suggestion should say enough.

Comment: *"It's a very high frequency question with a poor top answer. "* only 5 people out of 7715 who voted appear to think so. still if the top answer solves there problem then good for them but if not then they can just as easily scroll down and see the other answers. there is no excuse for a programmer not to do that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shouldn't edit an answer just to add links to the other answers given.

The [editing privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) page points out that some common editing reasons are:

> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks

Of course, editing is not limited just to these, but this indicates that edits should add substance to the answer, not change or detract from it.

While there are other solutions to this problem, the fact that that particular answer has over 10 times the upvotes of the next answer would suggest that most people found it useful. You don't need to add an index of alternatives because someone who doesn't find the accepted answer useful can just scroll down to the next answer and try that.

Comment: I see your point, but this answer is from 2009. Some of the mentioned possibilities weren't available in 2009 (to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages) And the popup (if you click on "answer") says "Also please note, that you can click on the edit link on any of these answers to improve them"

Comment: @AlexanderZ see it like this: you got the chance to show what you think should happen, and others got the chance to disagree with it. In a community driven website, wouldn't you call that a resounding success? That is completely in line with what the popup states. You *could* make the edit.